# Widget in ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#

I'm currently running into an issue with a web application where my Types and Services aren't being seen once deployed into the enterprise app.

I'm not getting any errors and can build the app in visual studio without errors. However, after I deploy my web app into the enterprise app. I get the following errors:

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MLTestWidget.Editor'.

Source Error:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeBehind="Editor.ascx.cs" Inherits="MLTestWidget.Editor" %>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplat>
```

I can get passed this issue by changing CodeBehind to CodeFile but then I get the following error:

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Service' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

```
Line 17:         //protected static log4net.ILog Log = 
EarthSoft.Common.log4net.GetLogger(typeof(Editor));
Line 18: 
Line 19:         protected Service Service = new Service();
Line 20: 
Line 21:     #region IWidgetEditor
```

It seems that once deployed into the enterprise app, it's not linking properly and not how I see it in visual studio?

Comment: There is no project type called `Enterprise App`. Web applications are *compiled* into DLLs, they don't generate compilation errors. The only way to get the error you mention is to create a web project, and *forget* to copy the referenced dlls to production

Comment: You are the man. I had to edit my properties to build the output dll to the production bin. Do you want to add this as a reply so we can mark it as a solution? Thanks again.